# How detect version of installed JRE

Tags: java

I'm develop cross-platform **standalone** application for Win and Mac.
Now I'm trying to check version of installed jre during runtime.
Is it possible? What are your suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following

```
System.getProperty("java.version");
```

Will give you the version of the jre installed. For a full list of system properties: [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html).

Comment: Thanks! It's really obviously :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `System.getProperty("java.version");`

Or try to execute `java -version.`